# has_many of itself through something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So, I have a system where users are able to follow authors (other users).

**User Model:**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :author_following, class_name: 'Following'
    has_many :following, through: :author_following, source: :author
    has_many :followers, foreign_key: 'author_id', through: :author_following, source: :user
  end
```

**Following Model:**

```
  class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :author, foreign_key: 'author_id', class_name: "User"
  end
```

**Issue:** I am able to get the list of authors that i am following, but I am able to get the list of my followers.

---

*Given: `u` is a valid user that is following others and has followers*

**`u.following`** generates the following SQL:

```
    SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "followings" ON "users"."id" = "followings"."author_id" WHERE "followings"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
```

Which is correct..

**`u.followers`** generates the following SQL:

```
    SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "followings" ON "users"."id" = "followings"."user_id" WHERE "followings"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
```

Which is wrong..

**Ideally** this SQL would be `WHERE "followings"."author_id" = $1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course,  I figure it your right after posting the question.  However if you think there is a more elegant way of doing this, please comment :)

To solve, I changed:

**User Model:**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :author_following, class_name: 'Following'
    has_many :following, through: :author_following, source: :author
    has_many :author_followers, foreign_key: 'author_id', class_name: 'Following'
    has_many :followers, through: :author_followers, source: :user
  end
```

**Following Model:**

```
  class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  end
```

Comment: 6 years later you saved my day, can't figure out of a better way to achieve this with rails 6

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. No second model needed.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'follower_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followees, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'followee_id'
end

# Migration
create_table :followees_followers do |t|
  t.belongs_to :followee
  t.belongs_to :follower
end
```

This is simpler, but the validation part(say verifying somebody is an author) need to be done in User model

Comment: Nice and simple.  I like it :D

Comment: @MichaelLynch, my pleasure. In theory it should work, though not verified:)

Comment: this will not work, rails will look for user_id on the other size of relationship

Answer (score 0):

@Billy Chan's answer above is close, but you also need to specify the other side of relationship as well with "association_foreign_key", and switch follower_id with followee_id on our side. Also, join table is users_users actually.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: 'User', 
     foreign_key: 'followee_id', association_foreign_key: 'follower_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followees, class_name: 'User', 
     foreign_key: 'follower_id', association_foreign_key: 'followee_id'
end

  # Migration
    create_table :users_users do |t|
       t.belongs_to :followee
       t.belongs_to :follower
    end
```

Now User.followers and User.followees work as expected